# Swift app crashing when attempting to fetch contacts

Tags: swift, asynchronous, contacts

I am creating an onboarding portion of an app which gets the user's contacts to check which already have the app to add as friends. I'm using the CNContact framework. I have created several methods I'm using to get a full list of the users' contacts, check if they have the app, and enumerate them in a UITableView. However, when the view loads, the app crashes with the error "A property was not requested when contact was fetched." I already make a fetch request with the keys CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, ad CNContactImageDataKey. I've included all my code here:

```
import Foundation
import Contacts
import PhoneNumberKit

struct ContactService {
    
    static func createContactArray() -> [CNContact] {
            
        var tempContacts = [CNContact]()
            
        let store = CNContactStore()
        store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, error) in
            if let _ = error {
                print("failed to request access to contacts")
                return
            }
            if granted {
                let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey]
                let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
                request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.familyName
                do {
                    try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stop) in
                    tempContacts.append(contact)
                    })
                } catch {
                    print("unable to fetch contacts")
                }
                
                print("created contact list")
            }
            
        }
            
        return tempContacts
            
    }
    
    static func createFetchedContactArray(contactArray: [CNContact], completion: @escaping ([FetchedContact]?) -> Void) -> Void {
        
        var temp = [FetchedContact]()
        getNumsInFirestore { (nums) in
            if let nums = nums {
                for c in contactArray {
                    let f = FetchedContact(cnContact: c, numsInFirebase: nums)
                    temp.append(f)
                }
                return completion(temp)
            } else {
                print("Error retrieving numbers")
            }
        }
        
        return completion(nil)
        
    }
    
    static func getNumsInFirestore(_ completion: @escaping (_ nums : [String]?) -> Void ) -> Void {
        var numsInFirebase = [String]()
        let db = FirestoreService.db

        db.collection(Constants.Firestore.Collections.users).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting user documents: \(err)")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                for doc in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let dict = doc.data()
                    numsInFirebase.append(dict[Constants.Firestore.Keys.phone] as! String)
                }
                completion(numsInFirebase)
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func getPhoneStrings(contact: CNContact) -> [String] {
        
        var temp = [String]()
        
        let cnPhoneNums = contact.phoneNumbers
        for n in cnPhoneNums {
            temp.append(n.value.stringValue)
        }
        
        return temp
        
    }
    
    static func hasBump(contact: CNContact, completion: @escaping (_ h: Bool) -> Void ) -> Void {
        
        let contactNums = ContactService.getPhoneStrings(contact: contact)
        ContactService.getNumsInFirestore { (nums) in
            if let nums = nums {
                return completion(contactNums.contains(where: nums.contains))
            } else {
                print("Error retrieving numbers from firestore")
                return completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func anyContactsWithBump(completion: @escaping (_ yes: Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let contacts = createContactArray()
        var tempBool = false
        let workgroup = DispatchGroup()
        
        for c in contacts {
            workgroup.enter()
            hasBump(contact: c) { (has) in
                if has {
                    tempBool = true
                }
                workgroup.leave()
            }
        }
        
        workgroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(tempBool)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Then I call the methods in the view controller class:

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class AddContactsVC: UIViewController {

    var fetchedContactsWithBump: [FetchedContact] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        let cnContacts = ContactService.createContactArray()
        
        var contactsWithBump = [CNContact]()
        
        let workgroup = DispatchGroup()
        
        for contact in cnContacts {
            workgroup.enter()
            ContactService.hasBump(contact: contact) { (has) in
                if has {
                    contactsWithBump.append(contact)
                }
                workgroup.leave()
            }
            
        }
        
        workgroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("Number of contacts with Bump: \(contactsWithBump.count)")
            ContactService.createFetchedContactArray(contactArray: contactsWithBump) { (fetchedContacts) in
                if let fetchedContacts = fetchedContacts {
                    self.fetchedContactsWithBump = fetchedContacts
                } else {
                    print("Error creating fetchedContacts array.")
                }
            }
        }
```

I also get the message "Error creating fetchedContacts array" in the console, so I know something is going wrong with that method, I'm just not sure what. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: The exception is thrown at 3 points: 1 at the first line of my FetchedContact init method, which looks like this:

```
init(cnContact: CNContact, numsInFirebase: [String]) {
    if cnContact.imageDataAvailable { self.image = UIImage(data: cnContact.imageData!) }
```

It also points to the line let f = FetchedContact(cnContact: c, numsInFirebase: nums) in createFetched contact array, and finally at my completion(numsInFirebase) call in getNumsInFirestore.

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: It's not giving me a line, just says so at the top of the AppDelegate class.

Comment: Try adding an "exception breakpoint" in your project.

Comment: Ok it shows the exception at 3 points: 1 at the first line of my FetchedContact init method, which looks like this:
```
init(cnContact: CNContact, numsInFirebase: [String]) {
        if cnContact.imageDataAvailable {
            self.image = UIImage(data: cnContact.imageData!)
        }
```
It also points to the line ```let f = FetchedContact(cnContact: c, numsInFirebase: nums)``` in createFetched contact array, and finally at my completion(numsInFirebase) call in getNumsInFirestore.

Comment: Please add additional information to your question - it is difficult to read in the comments.

Comment: Just updated the original post.

Comment: And what are the exceptions? Please review [ask] to optimize your question.

Comment: I wrote in the post initially, the exception is "A property was not requested when contact was fetched."

Comment: Ok, just making sure there was no additional info.

Answer (score 0):

To start with

```
 let contacts = createContactArray()
```

will always return an empty array.

This function has a return statement outside the closure so will immediately return an empty array.

Change createContactArray to use a completion handler like the other functions you have to populate contacts from inside the closure.

Comment: This actually isn't a problem - I added a print statement to see what the count of cnContacts is after being initialized and it's 127, which is the number of contacts on the phone I'm testing with.

Comment: That's highly unlikely with the code you've posted above. You set an empty array, call an async function, then return the array. At the point of the return the async function is unlikely to have populated the array. I wouldn't bet this code returns a non empty result every time.